# How to bind Google Places API to US Only Addresses?

Tags: jquery, forms, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Need some help here.

This is a good example of my setup and the form style I am using.
http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/form.html

My goal is to create a simple form that auto completes the form with city, state, once a user types in a valid zip code. It all works great, except that I cannot get it bound to US only addresses. On occasion, a valid 5 digit zip will be entered, but then auto populates to a non-US address.

To see what I mean, try typing "91333" in the example above, which is a CA zip code in the city of Pacoima. But you'll also see that it suggests Sweden and Slovakia as entries.

I've tried countless methods, including the country restriction:
componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}.

I've followed Google's methods, they document. In their example, they seem to have it working:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/faster-address-entry-with-google-places.html

But I think the solution has to be adapting what they have done into the GeoComplete Jquery plugin, as I have yet to get it to work.

Please help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need append the component restrictions to the request url:
Consider this example from the [geocode api docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ComponentFiltering):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=santa+cruz&components=country:ES&sensor=false

You should be able to pass a country when initialising the geocomplete.js plugin.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
      map: ".map_canvas",
      details: "form",
      country: "US",
      types: ["geocode", "establishment"]
    });

    $("#find").click(function(){
      $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
    });
  });
</script>
```

See [geocomplete.js on github](https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/blob/847dfefa61db8d2c06a28ddccf1fe8a5363f052a/jquery.geocomplete.js#L149-L151)

Comment: I also found an example with [country limits](https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/blob/master/examples/country_limit.html)

Comment: thanks for the response. I actually did try that with the country limits like that, but nothing worked. I can't tell if its an issue with the plugin, or simply that google is ignoring the restriction in their API.

Comment: Try downloading the github repo and open `/examples/country_limit.html` in a browser - it does work. There must be some other issue with your setup

Comment: I believe that was the answer (using their repo). The way I had the country bounds was incorrect. Thank you!